# kettle wildcard subdirectory regex

Tags: regex, kettle, pdi

I'm trying to process a file in a Kettle transformation. The targeted file has a static name, let's say `TARGETED.LOG` and it's in a subdirectory which contains a date component (variable) in his name. So, the whole path name will be something like:

> c:\username\kettleworkspace\report_[DDMMYYYY]\TARGETED.LOG.

Any advice?

[image: Kettle read file component configuration attached image]

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Get File Names` step with the `include subfolders` option, and drop the resulting list of files in your `Text File Input` with the `Accept filenames from previous step` option.

Of course between these two step you would probably want to add some `Filter` step.